# How to make changes in the GUI from a separate thread in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, java-threads

I am calling a thread from the main thread whose purpose is to process the data and then display it in the GUI. But when I try to open another view from that thread, it never works. The GUI doesn't change.

It's probably happening because only the main thread can change the GUI.

So how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Not the main thread, the Event Dispatch Thread.